# StackOverflowError when doing iterative computing using Apache-Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If a RDD object have non-empty `.dependencies`, does that means it have lineage? How could I remove it?

I'm doing iterative computing and each iteration depends on the result computed in previous iteration. After several iteration, it will throw `StackOverflowError`.

At first I'm trying to use `cache`, I read the code in `pregel.scala`, which is part of `GraphX`, they use a `count` method to materialize the object after `cache`, but I attached a debugger and seems such approach does not empty `.dependencies`, and that also does not work in my code.

Another alternative approach is using `checkpoint`, I tried `checkpoint` vertices and edges for my `Graph` object and then materialize it by `count` vertices and edges. Then I use `.isCheckpointed` to check if it is correctly checkpointed, but it always return false.

**Update**
I write a simplified version of code that could reproduce the problem.

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HDTM")
      .setMaster("local[4]")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.kryo.registrator", "edu.nd.dsg.hdtm.util.HDTMKryoRegistrator")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val v = sc.parallelize(Seq[(VertexId, Long)]((0L, 0L), (1L, 1L), (2L, 2L)))
    val e = sc.parallelize(Seq[Edge[Long]](Edge(0L, 1L, 0L), Edge(1L, 2L, 1L), Edge(2L, 0L, 2L)))
    val newGraph = Graph(v, e)
    var currentGraph = newGraph
    val vertexIds = currentGraph.vertices.map(_._1).collect()

    for (i <- 1 to 1000) {
      var g = currentGraph
      vertexIds.toStream.foreach(id => {
        g = Graph(currentGraph.vertices, currentGraph.edges)
        g.cache()
        g.edges.cache()
        g.vertices.cache()
        g.vertices.count()
        g.edges.count()
      })

      currentGraph.unpersistVertices(blocking =  false)
      currentGraph.edges.unpersist(blocking = false)
      currentGraph = g
      println(" iter "+i+" finished")
    }

  }
```

**Update**

Here is the code, I remove most of the unnecessary methods so the line of code is minimize, but it may not make sense if you consider about its functionality.

```
object StackOverFlow {
  final val PATH = "./"

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HDTM")
      .setMaster("local[4]")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.kryo.registrator", "edu.nd.dsg.hdtm.util.HDTMKryoRegistrator")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val filePath = PATH + "src/test/resources/binary.txt"
    val wikiGraph: Graph[WikiDataVertex, Double] = WikiGraphLoader.loadGraphFromTestHDTMFile(sc, filePath)
    wikiGraph.cache()
    val root = 0L
    val bfsGraph = GraphAlgorithm.initializeGraph(wikiGraph, root, sc)
    bfsGraph.cache()
    val vertexIds = bfsGraph.vertices.map(_._1).collect()
    var currentGraph = bfsGraph

    for (i <- 1 to 1000) {
      var g = currentGraph
      vertexIds.toStream.foreach(id => {
          g = samplePath(g, id, root)
      })

      currentGraph.unpersistVertices(blocking =  false)
      currentGraph.edges.unpersist(blocking = false)
      currentGraph = g
      println(" iter "+i+" finished")
    }

  }

  def samplePath[ED: ClassTag](graph: Graph[WikiDataVertex, ED],
                               instance: VertexId, root: VertexId): Graph[WikiDataVertex, ED] = {

    if(instance == 0L) return graph

    val (removedGraph, remainedGraph) = splitGraph(graph, instance)

    /**
     * Here I omit some other code, which will change the attributes of removedGraph and remainedGraph
     */

    val newVertices = graph.outerJoinVertices(removedGraph.vertices ++ remainedGraph.vertices)({
      (vid, vd, opt) => {
        opt.getOrElse(vd)
      }
    }).vertices

    val newEdges = graph.edges.map(edge => {
      if (edge.dstId == instance)
        edge.copy(srcId = edge.srcId) 
        // In the real case edge.srcId will be replaced by an vertexId calculated by other functions
      else
        edge.copy()
    })

    val g = Graph(newVertices, newEdges)
    g.vertices.cache()
    g.edges.cache()
    g.cache()
    g.vertices.count()
    g.edges.count()

    remainedGraph.unpersistVertices(blocking = false)
    remainedGraph.edges.unpersist(blocking = false)
    removedGraph.unpersistVertices(blocking = false)
    removedGraph.edges.unpersist(blocking = false)

    g
  }

  /**
   * Split a graph into two sub-graph by an vertex `instance`
   * The edge that ends at `instance` will lose
   * @param graph Graph that will be separated
   * @param instance Vertex that we are using to separate the graph
   * @tparam ED Edge type
   * @return (sub-graph with `instance`, sub-graph without `instance`)
   **/
  def splitGraph[ED: ClassTag]
  (graph: Graph[WikiDataVertex, ED], instance: VertexId): (Graph[WikiDataVertex, ED], Graph[WikiDataVertex,ED]) = {
    val nGraph = GraphAlgorithm.graphWithOutDegree(graph)
    // This will need twice, cache it to prevent re-computation
    nGraph.cache()

    val wGraph = nGraph.subgraph(epred = e => e.dstAttr._1.path.contains(instance) ||
      e.srcAttr._1.path.contains(instance),
      vpred = (id, vd) => vd._1.path.contains(instance))

    val woGraph = nGraph.subgraph(epred = e => !e.dstAttr._1.path.contains(instance) &&
      !e.srcAttr._1.path.contains(instance),
      vpred = (id, vd) => !vd._1.path.contains(instance))

    val removedGraph = Graph(wGraph.vertices.mapValues(_._1), wGraph.edges, null)
    val remainedGraph = Graph(woGraph.vertices.mapValues(_._1), woGraph.edges, null)

    removedGraph.vertices.count()
    removedGraph.edges.count()
    removedGraph.cache()
    remainedGraph.vertices.count()
    remainedGraph.edges.count()
    remainedGraph.cache()

    nGraph.unpersistVertices(blocking = false)
    nGraph.edges.unpersist(blocking = false)

    (removedGraph, remainedGraph)
  }

}
```

At first 10 iterations, it runs fast, after that each iteration takes a little bit more time. I check Spark WebUI, the actual execution time for each operation is almost the same, but as the iteration number increasing, `Scheduler Delay` will also increase. And after 20-ish iterations, it will throw StackOverflowError.

Comment: Could you put your code? Seems the `StackOverflowError` has nothing to do with RDD lineage.

Comment: StackOverflow might be related to some non-terminated recursion rather than RDD lineage. Yes, show some code.

Comment: @maasg I have attached the code, thanks for your help!

Comment: @bxshi could you please attach stack trace also? it would speed up diving into the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
val g = loadEdgeFile(sc, edge_pt, n_partition)

g.edges.foreachPartition(_ => Unit)
g.vertices.foreachPartition(_ => Unit)

g.checkpoint()

g.edges.foreachPartition(_ => Unit)
g.vertices.foreachPartition(_ => Unit)
println(s"is cp: ${g.isCheckpointed}"
```

In order to get a graph checkpoint, it should satisfy three conditions:

- the graph is no materialized before;
- then you checkpoint it;
- You should both materialize the vertices and edges.
  Then you check the status of the graph, you will get a true Answer.